# Windows: detect if feature SMB 1.0/CIFS file sharing support is on

Tags: windows, delphi, smb, cifs

Is there a way to detect in Delphi code if the Windows SMB 1.0/CIFS feature is on? I want my application to detect this so that I can warn users of vulnerability issues. I can't find any code examples anywhere, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft documents that SMB1 is enabled in the registry, and they document that checking the registrying is the way to go:

> [How to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3?tabs=server)

So you can check for the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
   @SMB1: DWORD
```

The default is "enabled", so if they key is not present, then it counts as *enabled*:

- SMB1=0: Disable
- SMB1=1: Enabled
- (missing): Enabled